# How to use `find` to find the indices of each page of a 3D matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d

I have a 3D matrix that each page/slice is independent of other slices. Thus, I would like to use the `find` command to filter my data in each page. However, when applied, `find` will return the indices in a row vector that describe my data as a whole, where actually it is not. For example:

```
a=rand(1,10,5);
ind=find(a<0.3);
```

This would return `ind` something like:

```
ind=
1 2 5 9 10 11 20 24 25 ...
```

I expected something like:

```
ind(:,:,1)=
1 2 3  

ind(:,:,2)=
1 5 6 10 %based on each slice, independent to other slices
```

I intended to do so (independently), so that I could apply the found indices to each slice of other matrix.

Can this be done without using loop? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since it is very likely, just like your example, that there will be different number of indices in each 3D slice that satisfy that condition, therefore you can't have a 3D array as the output. Number of elements in each slice of 3D array must be same. You will have to use a cell array for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ind2sub()` to convert your indices to subscripts. Something like this should work for a 3d array:

```
[i,j,k] = ind2sub(size(a), ind)
```

That said, the outputs (`i`, `j`, `k`), will all be the same size, that is the same size as `ind`. In other words, it gives one set of subscripts `(i,j,k)` (coordinates) for each value of `a<0.3`.

It's not completely clear what output you want/expect from your question, but if you want separate subscripts for each page in `a`, you'll have to filter further (e.g.  `j(i==1),k(i==1)` for the first page in `i`).

Comment: Can you explain more? What do I do with the `i j k`? Or how to form back the 3D matrix from those?

Comment: If you update your question to use reproducible data (i.e. don't use `rand()`, try something like `magic()`)  then it will more clear what you're trying to achieve!